# Update parent when any child is update with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a relation OneToMany, where the childs have OneToMany relation too...

I need order the grandfather by last modification, but the modification can be a child or grandchild... So, I have a modified column, but I need update it when I change a child or grandchild.

Any way to automatic the update the column from child/grandchild to parent?

Answer (score 0):

For me this is one of the cases in which the parent attribute of the entities in which it must have the relation of type Eager with type of cascade merge.

Being the parent eager attribute, in a relationship of 3 levels (grandfather, father, grandson) you will bring a maximum of 3 objects which will not penalize memory.

This together with the cascade type merge will allow you to do for example:

```
granchild.setField1(1)
granchild.setField2(2)
granchild.setDateMod(new Date());
granchild.getParent().setDateMod(new Date());
granchild.getParent().getParent().setDateMod(new Date());

entityManager.merge(granchild);
```

In such a way that you will update the audit field of the 3 objects.

We tend to think that we always have to use Lazy relationships, and in most cases this is the case, but sometimes in a scenario with few entities, using an eager relationship type can make life easier for us.